# how to test if a div contains another div

Tags: jquery, hide

```
<div class="contact-area">
  <div class="media-contact">name, email etc goes here...</div>
</div>
```

I need to check if div contact-area has div media-contact, if not then hide the contact-area as it has a colored background, and i dont want to have an empty colored background.

This is not working.please help.

```
$('.contact-area').each(function() {
    var ContactAreaEmpty= $('.contact-area:not(:has(.media-contact)');
    ContactAreaEmpty.hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$('.contact-area').not(':has(.media-contact)').hide();​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/UtF4G/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.contact-area' ).each( 
    function( i,t ){
        !$( '.media-contact', t ).length && $( t ).hide();
    }
);
```

http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-test999 for all those speed haters out there

Comment: This will hide all elements with class `contact-area` if even one is found without a child element with class `media-contact`.

Comment: @BryanDowning. You probly wanted to comment that on Adam's answer. Cause this one would work

Comment: BOOM take that @BryanDowning short circuit evaluation FTW

Comment: Rather, it will only hide elements with class `contact-area` if none have a child element with class `media-contact`.

Comment: You're almost there @samccone! If you change `$('.contact-area').hide()` to `$(t).hide()` then you have a very inefficient yet functional one liner.

Comment: flip forgot it in my one line

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.contact-area').each(function(){
    if($(this).has('.media-contact').length == 0){  
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This does exaclty what you asked. The find return an array of all found element. So if the array is empty well mediaContact aint there!

```
var mediaContact = $('.contact-area').find(".media-contact");

if (mediaContact.length <= 0) {
    $('.contact-area').hide();
}
```

Comment: Same problem as samccone's original answer - this will only hide elements with class `contact-area` if none have a child element with class `media-contact`.

Comment: @Bryan Downing. True its not a generic answer, it was a fast one to solve Anjana's question, and it did...

Comment: Making the assumption that there is only one element on the page with class `contact-area` is short sighted. I'm not trying to be a jerk here, just saying that code written to solve one problem in one situation often causes more problems than it solves. If the element was `#contact-area` instead of `.contact-area`, then this solution would have merit.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($('.contact-area').children().length > 0)
```